# What happens when choosing Magicka, Health or Stamina when leveling up in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When leveling up in Skyrim you have to choose between increasing your Magicka, Health or Stamina in addition to gaining a perk point. What effects does your choice have? Are there any effects apart from simply having more Magicka, Health or Stamina available?

Comment: Choosing Stamina will increase your maximum carrying capacity by 5.

Comment: I think it also regenarates the stats when you increase one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost nothing. That choice basically is the new replacement for the old attributes in the previous games.

The developers said that the old attributes were basically just a fancy way to raise or lower Health, Magicka or Stamina (besides also influencing skills, obviously), so they went for this "choose between the three" plus "perks" system.

The only thing that changes is the amount you can carry. As Arkvive pointed out, choosing stamina will increase your maximum carry capacity by 5.

Comment: quite a dramatic change from past games but I love it. makes leveling up a whole lot easier :)

Answer (score 5):

Choosing Stamina increases not only your availiable Stamina pool, but also your carrying capacity.

Additionally, whichever attribute you choose will be refilled to full. This means that you can 'save' a level up and apply the points in combat as a sort of poor mans potion.

Comment: I chose stamina at level up and had my health refilled. I was out of combat, which may or may not affect this.

Comment: It refills all 3 stats once you make a choice.

Comment: I can verify that on PC it does refill all three on leveling up.  It may not have been that way at some point in development/beta because I've read about it on refilling the one you pick.

Comment: It's true. When you pick one stat to level up, all three states are immediately raised to full. This can be used as an emergency replenishment of your stats during a dire situation.